# setting up DNS using CloudFlare

Tags: dns-hosting, cloudflare

I've got a few domains I'm forwarding to a single server using CloudFlare.  They're all basically set up the same, the only difference is the domain names.  In my CloudFlare DNS page they look like this:

```
Type     Name               Value                   
A        nemodate.com       points to 96.XX.XX.XX   
CNAME    www                is an alias of p9-pprr.geo.premiumservices.yahoo.com    
MX       nemodate.com       mail handled by mx1.biz.mail.yahoo.com
NS       nemodate.com       managed by yns1.yahoo.com   
NS       nemodate.com       managed by yns2.yahoo.com
```

My question is this: all 3 sites work fine with Host Name binding on my Windows 2012 Essentials server, but only the non-www version of the domain.  So, "nemodate.com" directs the user to the website, but "www.nemodate.com" shows error page `HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.`  This is true for all 3 websites.  In my Host Name bindings I have records for both nemodate.com and www.nemodate.com pointing to port 80 on the server.

If I go to my CloudFlare setup page and try to enter a new A record for www.nemodate.com, I get an error message that says `A CNAME already exists with that host.`

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

A CNAME already does exist. It's right there in the output you showed. If you don't want it, then remove it.

Comment: If I remove it, will both nemodate.com and www.nemodate.com resolve properly?

Answer (score 0):

DNS rookie error.

The CNAME has to be an alias of the domain name.  I don't know where I got "p9-pprr.geo.premiumservices.yahoo.com" from, but I changed that to "nemodate.com" and it worked.

I'm learning.  :o)